# When to use "is" and when to use "was" in this sentence?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I don't know if it is legit to ask this. English is my second language and I always have this tenses questions on how to use present or past tense in the same sentence.

> All properties were sold on 25th May, 2011, the selling price is $500,000.00.

For the first part of the sentence, because all properties were sold on 25th, we should use "were". But in the second part, should we use the selling price "was" or "is"? Is it grammatically correct to use "is" because the sold properties are still $500,000 today or should we use "was" because the price was in the past?

Comment: There's a useful tense chart at http://english.stackexchange.com/a/21847/18696

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is governed by ‘pragmatics’, the knowledge and interest you and your hearers or readers bring to the situation, rather than abstract grammar.

If you were speaking of qualities of the properties which endure into the present, you may use the present tense:

> I bought a new coat last fall. It **is** orange and **has** a hood. If you find it, please let me know.
>
> All properties were sold on 25th May, 2011. They **consist** of a .25-acre lot with a 2-bedroom house and an adjacent .25-acre lot where the new owners **are** now putting in an elaborate garden.

But you are not **required** to use the present. You do so only if your topic, the matter you are talking about, involves the current status of the properties. If on the other hand your topic is the status at the time of the sale or the transaction itself, you use the past.

> I bought a new coat last fall. It **was** orange and **had** a hood, and it kept me warm all winter.
>
> All properties were sold on 25th May, 2011. They consist**ed** of a .25-acre lot with a 2-bedroom house and an adjacent .25-acre lot, at that time undeveloped. The proceeds **were** used to pay off the estate taxes.

When it comes to the price, you are almost obliged to use the past tense: *The price **was** $500,000*. Markets change rapidly, so the price is in most circumstances a quality of the transaction, not the properties. If you say the price **is** $500,000, your hearers will infer that the properties are now being offered for sale again at an asking price of $500,000.